Me sale el error 1064 al tratar de generar el Forward Engineering en MySQL
buenas a todos, tengo el siguiente diagrama, al darle a la opción de "Forward Engineering" me salta el error 1064
Diagrama
Opciones de Forward Engineering
Código Generado por MySQL
Código generado por MySQL Forward Engineerign
Error arrojado:
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
SQL Code:
        CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `Pais_UNIQUE` ON `Usuarios`.`Pais` (`pais` ASC) VISIBLE

SQL script execution finished: statements: 12 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Soy estudiante, llevo ya dos semanas tratando de darle solución pero no he podido, espero obtener respuestas con la ayuda de ustedes.

Es porque el diagrama lo creas con Workbench (hecho para MySQL) y lo estás tratando de exportar directamente desde ahí hacia un MariaDB. El problema es que hay ciertas incompatibilidades, pero es sencillo de resolver.
En vez de hacer FW Engineering directamente a otra BD, exporta el código SQL a un archivo.
File > Export > Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script...
Luego edita el archivo SQL generado y elimina todas las palabras VISIBLE.
Mira esta pregunta, y esta otra.
Finalmente desde PhpMyAdmin http://localhost/phpmyadmin en Xampp, puedes importar el SQL y crear la estructura.

Muchísimas gracias!!!
